# Why Does presentModalViewController:animated: Turn The Background Black?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using **presentModalViewController:animated:** and while functionally it works correctly visually it has an artifact I want to remove. When the modally presented viewController appears its parent viewController is completely hidden with the background turning black. This is not what I want. My child viewController's view is translucent and I want to reveal the parent viewControllers view behind it. The effect I want is a piece of tracing paper sliding over the background.

I assumed **presentModalViewController:animated:** supported this. Is that not the case?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*NavigationController* and the *View Controllers* are designed in such a way that **only one view controller may show at a time**. When a new view controller is pushed/presented the previous view controller will be hidden by the system. So when you reduce the modal view's *alpha* you will possibly see the *window's backgroundColor* (the *black color* you see now).

If you want a translucent view to slide-in over the main view, you can add the view as the *subView* of main view and animate it using *UIView Animations*.

Comment: Sigh, I was afraid of that. Its unfortunate since compositing is so fundamental to UIKit. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This may get you what you want:

```
presentingViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Answer (score 2):

`presentingViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;`
 doesn't work after ios7,you can fix it by after

`presentingViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

presentingViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;`

then both:
`[appViews.rootViewController presentViewController:presentingViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: It's worth noting that you can set this via the Interface builder on a modally presented Segue.